# Path setting for Compiling a Native C/C++ Program from the Command Line

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Using VC++ Command Line for the first time. Facing problem in setting proper paths for cl.exe and other header files:

```
///simple.cpp, saved at **D:\Program Files\VC** 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is a native C++ program." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When typing on command:

```
cl /EHsc simple.cpp
```

returning error

```
D:\Program Files\VC> cl /EHsc simple.cpp
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**Kindly note my Visual Studio is installed in D-drive.**

As a work around I moved to bin folder where cl.exe is present:

```
 D:\Program Files\VC\bin>cl /EHsc simple.cpp
 Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 simple.cpp
 simple.cpp(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such
 file or directory
```

As you can see now it is unable to include "iostream", which is present in include folder under  D:\Program Files\VC\include

Please help me in setting the default paths properly.

Update:

Here are the content of the directory:

```
 Directory of D:\Program Files\VC

 06/15/2012  02:23 PM    <DIR>          .
 06/15/2012  02:23 PM    <DIR>          ..
 04/20/2012  12:24 PM    <DIR>          atlmfc
 06/15/2012  02:35 PM    <DIR>          bin
 04/20/2012  12:22 PM    <DIR>          crt
 04/20/2012  12:24 PM    <DIR>          include
 04/20/2012  12:24 PM    <DIR>          lib
 02/23/2012  05:16 PM             1,525 Notepad.lnk
 04/20/2012  12:23 PM    <DIR>          redist
 06/15/2012  02:31 PM               146 simple.cpp
 04/20/2012  12:22 PM    <DIR>          VCAddClass
 04/20/2012  12:21 PM    <DIR>          VCContextItems
 08/31/2009  02:46 AM               160 vcEmptyTestProject.vsz
 04/20/2012  12:21 PM    <DIR>          VCNewItems
 04/20/2012  12:22 PM    <DIR>          vcpackages
 04/20/2012  12:21 PM    <DIR>          VCProjectDefaults
 04/20/2012  12:25 PM    <DIR>          vcprojectitems
 04/20/2012  12:25 PM    <DIR>          vcprojects
 04/20/2012  12:22 PM    <DIR>          VCResourceTemplates
 09/30/2009  08:23 PM             1,237 vcvarsall.bat
 04/20/2012  12:25 PM    <DIR>          VCWizards
           4 File(s)          3,068 bytes
          17 Dir(s)   8,465,346,560 bytes free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For visual studio 2008 there is an environment variable: VS90COMNTOOLS that you can use.  Probably something similar for VS2010.

so:
from the command line directly, or from a batch file:
"%VS90COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"

(include the quotes!)

This should set up stuff appropriately.

You'll need to replace %VS90COMNTOOLS% with the appropriate environment variable for 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Visual Studio Command Prompt, it's a command prompt that comes ready with the appropriate directories in the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
"d:\program files\bin\vcvars32.bat"
```

This file is created for you when you install the compiler, so it has values customized for your installation.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx) for details.